# passing commands to PUTTY

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I use the following code to open putty terminal and pass a command. The terminal opens fine, but further nothing happens. The script just stops until I close the terminal. What could cause a problem here?

```
import subprocess, time
test=subprocess.Popen('"C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\putty.exe" -ssh -X -I
        p:\.ssh\id_dsa.ppk my_name@my_host', 
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
test.stdin.write("ls\n")
test.stdin.flush()
test.stdin.close()
stdout_value = test.stdout.read()
print repr(stdout_value)
print 'done'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`putty.exe` does not read from standard input, and does not write to standard output.  It is a terminal emulator, so it takes input from the keyboard and writes to its application window.

If you want to pass data through standard input and output descriptors into an ssh connection then use the `plink.exe` program that comes with the PuTTY package.  (It will be in the same directory as `putty.exe`.)  It's not a terminal emulator, it just makes an ssh connection and then drives stdin and stdout, similar to the traditional `ssh` command on Unix-like systems.

You might even be able to run `ssh` instead of `plink`, depending on what Windows release you have and what extra packages you have installed.

Also, I believe both `plink` and `ssh` want `-i` (lower case), not `-I` (upper case) as the option for specifying a key file.

Comment: Thank you, this helps. The only problem now is that the code stops at `stdout_value = test.stdout.read()` until I close `plink` process via Task Manager
You are absolutely right about -i, capital I in my question is a typo